# Error with Azure Synapse DEP-enabled workspaces

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a synapse workspace with DEP-enabled. As pypi libraries cannot be installed directly in spark pool. I used the method, although the installation worked fine. I am still not able to use the REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-python-packages#install-wheel-files

Would be great if you could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> This is a [Known limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-create-a-workspace-with-data-exfiltration-protection#known-limitations) for synapse workspace with data exfiltration protection enabled.

Users can provide an environment configuration file to install Python packages from public repositories like PyPI. In data exfiltration protected workspaces, **connections to outbound repositories are blocked**. As a result, Python library installed from public repositories like **PyPI are not supported**.

As an alternative, users can upload workspace packages or create a private channel within their primary Azure Data Lake Storage account. For more information, visit [Package management in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-azure-portal-add-libraries).

Comment: I already tried it, it does install all the packaged. But as soon as I am using doing REST API calls, its again throwing error.

Comment: Could you please share the REST API call which you are trying along with the error message?